# The connection pool for database '/data/data/msv_database.db' has been unable to grant a connection. Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 0 available

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I m getting following error:while accessing database from two different threads using single  database object throughout the application

The connection pool for database
'/data/data/msv_database.db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 802 (
Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 0 available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection pool has been unable to grant a connection to thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742464/connection-pool-has-been-unable-to-grant-a-connection-to-thread)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably you want to select query on a table which is used on a transaction without ended transaction before. Try to execute `endTransaction()` on finally block of transaction.

OR

You are updating two tables and two different transactions are holding different tables waiting for the other to release.

OR

Simply that there are just too many open connections and the DB or connection pool just gets confused.

Whatever it is, something is probably wrong out of the above. Check carefully.

More - [Connection pool has been unable to grant a connection to thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742464/connection-pool-has-been-unable-to-grant-a-connection-to-thread).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is relevant to what you are facing. I am keeping a hold of SQLiteOpenHelper within a contentProvider. I was adding to my CRUD operations  db.beginTransaction, db.setTransactionSuccessful, and db.endTransaction. I removed them, and that solved the issue I was having as I was calling my contentProvider from a loader and an intentService. Strange, many have mentioned that these commands are important to avoid the error.

https://github.com/juanmendez/jm_android_dev/blob/master/12.alarms/06.magazineAppWithAlarm/app/src/main/java/info/juanmendez/android/intentservice/service/provider/crud/MagazineCrud.java