# Does SQLite for Android support multithreading access?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

When I try to access SQLite database in different threads in my Android app I get an error:

```
W/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database ' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 289045
```

Does somebody know if it is possible to access SQLite Android database from the different threads?

Comment: Have not tested it but looks similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/11742464/3904645 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25563417/3904645